# How do I achieve this contour effect with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve this effect.

I'm referring to the contour of the black parts.

Thanks for the tip in advance

[image: effect]

Comment: This is an image trace most likely from Illustrator. Just do it in there.

Comment: Kind of impossible to tell. There's no filter to produce such an edge. Chances are it was a photo or scan of something (furry) then adjusted to be a silhouette.

Comment: I'd say... `Image > Adjustments > Threshold...`. Depending on the image, the edge may already be fairly close to something like that in some places. If you want to make the edge blotchy like that throughout the whole edge, you could perhaps use: `Filter gallery > Distort > Ocean Ripple`, then you could perhaps blur it a tiny bit `Filter > Blur > Gaussian blur...` and use `Threshold` again (maybe).`Threshold` makes the edge very sharp, so you may want to use `Gaussian Blur` again just a tiny bit. Something like that...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "contour effect".  That's not how I would describe it. It looks like a failed attempt at using the posterize or threshold filter, or using the cutout filter perhaps, or some combination of those.  Who knows!

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info! I managed to get an accurate result thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a photo of a person that has been posterized -- reduced to just black and white. However, the original photo might have been grainy, very contrasty, or processed in some way to make the transitions from light to dark very blotchy, which resulted in the "furryness" of the edges when it was converted to black and white using the Threshold or Posterize filters.

Comment: Thanks! The Threshold filter gave a pretty accurate result. The original image is just a screencap from a video, so the edges are not like that in the original one.